# logstash Pipeline terminated

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration, elk

logstash pipeline is terminating after sometime with below error.

```
[2023-12-09T20:30:02,848][ERROR][logstash.javapipeline    ][CBC-only-B] Pipeline worker error, the pipeline will be stopped {:pipeline_id=>"CBC-only-
B", :error=>"(ArgumentError) string contains null byte", :exception=>Java::OrgJrubyExceptions::ArgumentError, :backtrace=>["org.jruby.RubyFile.expand
_path(org/jruby/RubyFile.java:848)", "finapp.logstash_minus_8_dot_3_dot_3.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_5_dot_0.gems.logstash_minus_output_minus_file_mi
nus_4_dot_3_dot_0.lib.logstash.outputs.file.inside_file_root?(/finapp/logstash-8.3.3/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-file-4.3.0/lib/lo
gstash/outputs/file.rb:171)", "finapp.logstash_minus_8_dot_3_dot_3.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_5_dot_0.gems.logstash_minus_output_minus_file_minus_4_d
ot_3_dot_0.lib.logstash.outputs.file.event_path(/finapp/logstash-8.3.3/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-file-4.3.0/lib/logstash/outputs
/file.rb:177)", "finapp.logstash_minus_8_dot_3_dot_3.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_5_dot_0.gems.logstash_minus_output_minus_file_minus_4_dot_3_dot_0.lib
.logstash.outputs.file.multi_receive_encoded(/finapp/logstash-8.3.3/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-file-4.3.0/lib/logstash/outputs/fi
le.rb:113)", "org.jruby.RubyArray.each(org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1821)", "finapp.logstash_minus_8_dot_3_dot_3.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_5_dot_0.gems.
logstash_minus_output_minus_file_minus_4_dot_3_dot_0.lib.logstash.outputs.file.multi_receive_encoded(/finapp/logstash-8.3.3/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0
/gems/logstash-output-file-4.3.0/lib/logstash/outputs/file.rb:112)", "finapp.logstash_minus_8_dot_3_dot_3.logstash_minus_core.lib.logstash.outputs.ba
se.multi_receive(/finapp/logstash-8.3.3/logstash-core/lib/logstash/outputs/base.rb:103)", "org.logstash.config.ir.compiler.OutputStrategyExt$Abstract
OutputStrategyExt.multi_receive(org/logstash/config/ir/compiler/OutputStrategyExt.java:143)", "org.logstash.config.ir.compiler.AbstractOutputDelegato
rExt.multi_receive(org/logstash/config/ir/compiler/AbstractOutputDelegatorExt.java:121)", "finapp.logstash_minus_8_dot_3_dot_3.logstash_minus_core.li
b.logstash.java_pipeline.start_workers(/finapp/logstash-8.3.3/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:300)"], :thread=>"#<Thread:0x368364b1 sleep
>"}
[2023-12-09T20:30:58,327][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][CBC-only-B] Pipeline terminated {"pipeline.id"=>"CBC-only-B"}
```

after changing the pipeline name in pipeline.yml file. its started again and working fine for sometime and then again terminated with same error.
I have another pipeline with exactly same config file and is working fine without any termination.

Comment: only solution is to run the logstash with automatic reload option and change the pipeline name whenever getting pipeline terminated error for that pipeline. pipeline gets reloaded and start working as expected.